# Flags to move the ipdb and iobj files from the Link Time Code Generation optimization (LTCG)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker

Setting the Time Code Generation optimization (/LTCG:incremental) flag will generate *.iobj and *.ipdb files at the same location of the EXE file ?

Is there a flag to create those files in another folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a missing feature:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a694f11-95b3-44a6-a1d5-575b4222652d/how-do-i-change-the-output-path-of-the-link-time-code-generation-iobj-ipdb-files-in-visual?forum=vcgeneral

What also doesn't work is changing the OutDir and just setting the Linker OutputFile to the location you want. the ipdb/iobj files will go along the OutputFile.